# <Filesmatch> not allowing files to display properly on custom 401 error page

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel, custom-error-pages, litespeed, errordocument

Not sure how to properly title this problem (my apologies). Recently my web hoster has upgraded from Apache to Litespeed. In doing so this has rendered my custom, “**401 error page/unauthorized login**” to not load properly.

Here is current .htaccess file stored in my “*public_html*” folder:

```
RewriteEngine on

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php|gif|jpe?g)$">
Require all granted
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 400 /.error400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /.error401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /.error403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /.error404.php

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected 'public_html'"
AuthUserFile "/home/dac/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
Require valid-user
```

Now when my error page loads, the only elements that are functioning are the hyperlinks. The 4 image files along with the .css file are not loading.

What my 401 error page looks like after an unsuccessful login attempt:

[image: My custom 401 error page]

Now in troubleshooting this last time, I know I had to alter the following code below in my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php|gif|jpe?g)$">
Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

I know I need something like `<FilesMatch>` to allow authentication and allow public access to this document. But with the upgrade from Apache to Litespeed I’m stuck. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

-X

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? You've enabled the rewrite engine (`RewriteEngine on`) for some reason? What HTTP response are the images and CSS file getting?

Comment: What files are you actually wanting to protect?

Comment: I am protecting the rest of my files on my “public_html” directory. You had helped me before with my images and css file not displaying properly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862309/cpanel-custom-401-error-page-not-displaying/64863594?noredirect=1#comment114680381_64863594                     Everything has remained the same, just that the webhoster switched from Apache to Litespeed. Now everything is back to square one...not displaying.

Comment: "I am protecting the rest of my files on my “public_html” directory." - Yes, but which files? Are there many different types? It's just that you are permitting unrestricted to _all_ "normal" website files (PHP, JS, CSS, images), it might be better to restrict access to only the files that need to be protected. (?)

Comment: The image below are the only files in the "public_html" the rest are file folders containing images:

[Screenshot - public_html](https://ibb.co/Zmwk49f)